# How do I stop MQTTClient from getting new data

Tags: ios, objective-c, mqtt, uibackgroundtask

I have an app which uses MQTTClient to connect to io.adafruit and then subscribes to various feeds.  I then publish a "GET" message to start receiving data from the various feeds.  Then I check the various feeds to see what they are and do whatever.
This is fine when the app is in the foreground but when it is put into the background I would like to stop the process.  I have tried setting the session to nil, disconnect the session, and set the MQTTCRSocketTransport to nil all to no avail.  It just keeps checking for updates.
This is my code.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.myUserName =  [defaults objectForKey:@"myUserNameFile"];
    NSLog(@"myUserName:%@",self.myUserName);
    self.myUserKey =  [defaults objectForKey:@"myUserKeyFile"];
    NSLog(@"myUserKey:%@",self.myUserKey);
    
    transport = [[MQTTCFSocketTransport alloc] init];
    transport.host = @"io.adafruit.com";
    transport.port = 1883;
    
    NSLog(@"transport:%@",transport);
    session2 = [[MQTTSession alloc] init];
    session2.userName =self.myUserName;
    session2.password = self.myUserKey;
    session2.transport = transport;
    
    session2.delegate = self;
    session2.keepAliveInterval = 30;
    NSString *feeds = [self.myUserName stringByAppendingString:@"/feeds/"];
    
    self.battery = [feeds stringByAppendingString:@"battery"];
    
    self.getbat = [self.battery stringByAppendingString:@"/get"];
    
     [session2 connectWithConnectHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if(!error){
                
          [session2 subscribeToTopic:self.battery atLevel:1 subscribeHandler:^(NSError *error, NSArray *gQoss){
                    
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Subscription failed %@", error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Subscription sucessfull! Granted Qos: %@", gQoss);
                
               
                NSData* data = [ @"0" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [session2 publishData:data onTopic:self.getbat retain:NO qos:0 publishHandler:nil];
                 }
        }]; }
            else {NSLog(@"[connectWithConnectHandler]Error Connect %@", error.localizedDescription);}
      }];
 }

- (void)newMessage:(MQTTSession *)session
              data:(NSData *)data
           onTopic:(NSString *)topic
               qos:(MQTTQosLevel)qos
          retained:(BOOL)retained
               mid:(unsigned int)mid {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 if ([topic isEqualToString:self.battery]){
       B = [dataString intValue];
       }

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{  [session2 disconnect];
   [session2 unsubscribeTopic:self.battery];
   NSLog(@"this enters background");}
```

Can someone help me stop the process when the app enters the background.  The biggest problem is that one of the feeds updates it data every 6seconds so when the app enters the background these updates keeps the app alive in the background.

Comment: You will see different behaviour depending on whether you are running under Xcode or not. Under Xcode your app has infinite background time. When not running under Xcode iOS will terminate your app after 30 seconds.  The correct thing to do is disconnect the client in `didEnterBackground`. If that isn't working then you probably aren't disconnecting the right client . Show that code

Comment: session2 is the client with the userName, password and transport and connectsWithConnectHandler.  I have put didEnterBackground in my code and tried it with the added code but nothing happens.  There is a didEnterBackground in the AppDelegate that works but since the Session2 is created in the main ViewController I can't put it into the AppDelegate.  I have tried to create session2 in the AppDelegate and use it in the ViewController but no go.  Thanks

Comment: `didEnterBackground` is an AppDelegate method. You can't just add it to any class and expect it to run. You need provide the `session2` object to the App Delegate or you can observe the did enter background `NSNotification` in your other class.  Really your view controller should not own the MQTT session.  That should be in some other object that both the view controller and the app delegate can reference.

Comment: Background task is not reliable enough for my needs so I will be deleting this post.